# How To Trace A Tricky JavaFx Freeze / Hang Randomly

Tags: java, javafx

I am facing this issue of `JavaFx` thread freezing randomly, found a solution online i.e

```
<jvmArgs>
    <jvmArg>-Dprism.verbose=true</jvmArg>
    <jvmArg>-Dprism.order=sw</jvmArg>
</jvmArgs>
```

Can anyone help me in where to implement this code?

Comment: Why do you think that switching to pure software rendering solves any of your problems?

Comment: You can print out a stack trace of every existing thread, including the JavaFX application thread, by sending SIGQUIT to the Java process in Unix (that is, kill -QUIT java-process-id).  In Windows, pressing Ctrl-Break in the program’s command window does the same thing.

Comment: Maybe it is caused by unicode in a ListView on linux https://github.com/FAForever/downlords-faf-client/issues/1353

Comment: Try updating to the newest version, google for similar issue. You could possibly make a Thread dump and see where the javafx thread stops, tho interpreting the results is really hard.

Comment: I shall try to provide a thread dumb when this happens and revert ..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In general without more information if a program hangs you can do a [thread dump](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/generating-a-thread-dump-externally-182158040.html). Interpreting the result might be tricky, so this is something for advanced users. You could now see where the java fx UI thread(also called main thread or application thread) is and what it is doing. Maybe it is waiting or it is running in circles(would need several dumps to see that).

Tho given your description it sounds like a linux/javafx bug. I faced several of them lately. One example https://github.com/FAForever/downlords-faf-client/issues/1353 .

Comment: Please find [thread dump](https://pastebin.com/TGxageYn). Also note once the JavaFx Freezes and i try to close the Application, it remains in the background which later does not allow my application to open again

Comment: The stack trace looks ok no idea

Comment: if u close the application and it is not terminating that means u have running none deamon threads